# PHP/SQL fetch query data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I'm having a problem in this simple SQL/PHP query...

```
<?php
$course=$row['course'];
include('../db.php');
$cat=$row['cat'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE course='$course' AND cat='$cat'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['question'].'?<br>';
        $qid=$row['qid'];
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="qqqq[]" value="'.$qid.'" />';
        echo '<select name="answer[]">';
        echo '<option>Select Answer></option>';
        $resultik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question='$qid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
            while($rowik = mysql_fetch_array($resultik))
                {
                echo '<option>';
                echo $rowik['opt'];
                echo '</option>';
                }
        echo '</select><br><br>';
    }
?>
```

Basically, this is a online examination. I want to display all the questions if the student will login. And the questions will be order/arrange according by their course. But eventually, there's no display at all. Not even a single letter will display.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where is `$row` defined for `$course=$row['course'];
include('../db.php');
$cat=$row['cat'];`?

Comment: A blank screen with PHP usually means a syntax error in your code. Your server error log will show you where.

Comment: Hello Frank, the  db.php include the connection of the database..

Comment: Hello Hobo, nothing display after executing my code. I don't know what really is wrong..

Comment: Deprecated mysql. Please read the following for your own benefit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: That error (in the answer below which should be deleted) means your `$row` is undefined or at least the index you're trying to access, `cat` and `course`.

Comment: It would be useful to post the error you got here as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: $row should be define above all or if it is defined in anyother file it should be included above

Comment: I don't have any textfields in this.. I just want to display all the questions according to the course of the student if they login.. I just run the SQL query that Imran gave, it says that Undefined Variable cat and course..

Answer (score 1):

In this there must some POST or GET values to get the **course** and **cat** which means

```
$course=$row['course'];
$cat=$row['cat'];
```

Since the $row is empty this is the case it will not display anything. Check with isset() like following

```
$course = isset($row['course']) ?  $row['course'] : 'COURSE';
$cat    = isset($row['cat']) ? $row['cat'] : 'CAT';
```

The included file **include('../db.php');** please check the database connectivity has established or not?.

Comment: Thanks Jagadessh, It displays now the content but not in order.. I'm using WHERE condition in mysqli, is WHERE condition id deprecated in mysqli? Is there any other way? this is my sql code `code`SELECT * FROM question WHERE course='$course' `code` but it's not showing anything. But if I remove the where condition it shows all the content..

Comment: try to echo your value **$course** or your query and check with your database directly.

Another way set the default course example `code` SELECT * FROM question WHERE course='php'  `code`

If it works then please check with the values of $course.

Comment: It already show up now Jagadeesh. Thanks for that. One more thing, how can I display it according to the subject. I'm using accordion style. And this is now it looks like [link]http://prntscr.com/6u0m1d[link] . I have 4 courses and same question every course, but It displays it all in one accordion.. I want them to order or arranged by subject.

Comment: you can use `code` ORDER BY subject `code` in your query so that it can order based on the subject, Results will display in the accordion. am not sure. please try.

Comment: The subjects is on the other table, and I need to create a inner join query where I can arranged them by subject. Here's my SQL Query, `code` SELECT * FROM question INNER JOIN subject ON subject = cat WHERE course='$course' AND cat='$cat' ORDER BY `subject` `code` I have question and subject tables in my database.